# onchange text on javascript woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php

```PHP-HTML-JS
<?php
echo'
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="falk_id" name="falk"   value="" maxlength="4"/>
    <input type="text" id="dis_id"  name="coupon" value="" maxlength="4"/>
  </form>
  <script>
    var falakTayebElement = document.getElementById("falk_id");
    var discountElement   = document.getElementById("dis_id");
    var totalPoints       = <?php echo $points;?>;

    falakTayebElement.onchange = function() {
      var points                  = parseInt(falakTayebElement.value);
      var discount                = points / 3 ;
      discountElement.value       = "saasa";
      //discountElement.innerHTML = discount.toFixed(2);
    };

    discountElement.onchange = function() {
      var discount = parseFloat(discountElement.value);
      var points   = discount * 3;
      if(points > totalPoints) {
        falakTayebElement.style.color = "red"; // to show error text
        falakTayebElement.value       = "ليس لديك رصيد كافي من النقاط !"
      } else {
        falakTayebElement.value       = points.toFixed(2);
      }
    }
  </script>';
  }
?>
```

I don't know what's wrong here, but by changing the element I didn't get any result on the other textfeild.
#javascript #php #woocommerce
any advice, notes..?

Comment: The first thing that is very wrong here, is that you are outputting large chunks of mostly static HTML using echo. You should read https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: And _because_ you are still within a text literal that you are echo-ing, using `<?php echo $points;?>` _again_ in that place, makes no sense.

Comment: Please add the rendered HTML, not the PHP code you use to derive the HTML.

Comment: If you had done your indentation correctly (I did it for you) you would have immediately noticed that there is an extra  closing brace. so it's a typo mistake

Comment: if you put the scripts on the body it will work

Comment: thanks alot guys, finally I knew where I was stucking.
much apperciation!